# Why doesn't momentum operator's eigenket expected to be a parity eigenket?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am reading the 4th chapter of Sakurai where it says that

> The momentum operator anti-commutes with the parity operator, so the momentum eigenket is not expected to be a parity eigenket.

Why is it so? Position operator also anti-commutes with parity operator. Is the above statement true for position operator as well?

Further, it says that

> angular momentum is expected to be a parity eigenket because it
>   commutes with parity operator.

What is the relation between commutation/anti-commutation with being the parity operator?

Comment: Well, yes, the text just showed you $\pi |x\rangle= |-x\rangle\neq \alpha |x\rangle$, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, any two hermitian operators that commute with each other (compatible observables) can be simultaneously diagonolized and therefore share the same eigenkets.

If $\{{\bf p},{\bf \pi}\}=0$, therefore, $[{\bf p},{\bf\pi}]\not=0$; so, $\bf{p}$ and $\bf{\pi}$ do not share the same eigenkets. (${\bf p}$: momentum, ${\bf\pi}$: parity)